# Sumar dos Arrays en forma de lista y viseversa

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Tengo los Arrays a y b

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [15,25,35]
```

y tengo la variale v

```
v = 36
```

donde **v** es la suma de alguna de las combinaciones entre **a** y **b**, es decir (según el ejemplo): `v = a[0] + b[2]` sé que tengo que sumar cada elemento del array **a** con cada elemento del array **b** y así sucesivamente hasta encontrar **v**, pero no sé como hacerlo en **javascript**

también quiero saber como invertir el orden para sumarlo de todas las maneras posibles, ya que me hacen un test cambiando los arrays y el código debe seguir funcionando

Comment: O sea que pretendes sumar ¿ **1 + 2 + 3 + 15 + 25 + 35** ? Y además para que quieres invertir el orden del Array para sumarlo si te va a seguir dando el mismo resultado en todos los casos....

Comment: Bienvenido. Incluyes dos preguntas lo que la hace demasiado amplia, pero no incluye lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema lo que la hace poca clara. Para más detalles sobre lo que se espera en las preguntas en este sitio,  sigue el [tour] y revisa [ask].

Comment: lo que quieres puedes hacerlo con el siguiente código: `for (x in a) { for (y in b) {  if ( v == a[x] + b[y] ) {   console.log("v = a["+x+"] + b["+y+"]");  }; };};`

Comment: ¿Algún motivo especial para reabrir esta pregunta? Sigue sin aclarar lo que pregunta, por ejemplo la parte que pone "también quiero saber como invertir el orden para sumarlo de todas las maneras posibles, ya que me hacen un test cambiando los arrays y el código debe seguir funcionando".